# Adding item on array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

im having a difficulties on leaning javascript, what i want to achieve is to add an item on the top of the list instead on the Last index.

below is my code:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.push("Lemon");
```

i need to insert the Lemon before Banana..

thanks!

Comment: `fruits.unshift("Lemon")` or `fruits = ["Lemon", ...fruits]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
fruits.unshift("Lemon");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `unshift()`, as told before, but I would recommend learning `splice()`.

Basically `splice()` can be used for adding and removing elements from an array:

**Removing**:

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var newArr = myArray.splice(1, 2); // starting from index 1 take two elements from `myArray` and put them into `newArr`
```

Results:

- `myArray`: `[ 1, 4, 5 ]`,
- `newArr`: `[ 2, 3 ]`

**Adding**:

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
myArray.splice(1, 0, "test"); // starting from index 1 take zero elements and add "test" to `myArray`
```

Result:

- `myArray`: `[ 1, "test", 2, 3, 4, 5 ]`

Answer (score 1):

Use `unshift` instead of `push`

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.unshift("Lemon");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use array `splice` method

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.splice(0, 0, "Lemon")
console.log(fruits)
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/f7uxo7gx/)

Comment: unshift is fine since he is just a beginner.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy im just saying that it may add to his confusion. unshift was PREDEFINED to do exactly what he is needing.

Answer (score 0):

I soted this out by using the unshift function

`var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.unshift("Lemon");`

hope it helps